# Manipulating a list by slicing in Python3.x

Tags: python, list, slice

Is there a way to slice a list every few items and then reverse them?
For example, can I turn:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

into:

```
7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

Is there a simple slice notation that could accomplish this goal similar to list[::-1] used to reverse the list?

Comment: "is there a ... slice notation that could accomplish this goal" Yes. "Is there a ***simple*** slice notation that could accomplish this goal" No. Hang on let me write something up....

Comment: I want to slice it every <int variable> items and then reverse them, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a slice notation for this, here is how I would probably do it (this is with Python 2.x, Python 3.x code is included at the end):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [x for s in reversed(zip(*[iter(lst)]*3)) for x in s]
[7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

This method for clustering elements into `n` length groups comes straight from the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) docs, so the approach here is to create your groups of 3, reverse the resulting list, and then use a list comprehension for flattening.

Or with the itertools module, using the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(reversed(list(grouper(lst, 3)))))
```

**Python 3 versions:**

For the first approach you will need to convert the generator returned by `zip` to a list, otherwise `reversed` will fail:

```
>>> [x for s in reversed(list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*3))) for x in s]
[7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

And in the itertools approach you just need to replace `izip_longest` with `zip_longest` in both the import statement and inside of the `grouper` function.

Comment: Just edited with the changes that are necessary for Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` can make something like this easy for you:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 10)
>>> result = a.reshape((3, -1))[::-1].ravel() #if you OK with getting np.array
>>> result
array([7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3])
```

If you want a list

```
>>> result = a.reshape((3, -1))[::-1].ravel().tolist() #if you want to get back a list
>>> result
[7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

This solution only works if a list can be divided into n equal parts.

Comment: It will account for being divided equally.  How does one import Numpy (I have never used it.)

Comment: I left out `import numpy as np`, but you have to have it installed.

Comment: So that implementation cannot be used where numpy isn't installed?

Comment: Yes. If you don't have `numpy` installed, you can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
QTYPERGROUP = 3
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

reversed_by_group = [el for sublist in list(reversed(list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*QTYPERGROUP)))) for el in sublist]
# [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

It's long and ugly, but it does the job. Note that this only works if `len(lst) % QTYPERGROUP == 0`, otherwise it will ignore the rest. For example

```
QTYPERGROUP = 4
reversed_by_group = [el for sublist in list(reversed(list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*QTYPERGROUP)))) for el in sublist]
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4] there's no "9"
```